# "Follow Active Quads" Behavior: is it correct or not?

Tags: uv

Please kindly view the screenshot below: The left side of the object with a green line around it is what I intend to unwrap.

[image]

The orange shape labeled as "1" is the final UV form I want to achieve, simply because if you *unwrap* that piece, this is the shape you will get. So, I adjusted a single polygon to the axes X and Y, selected the polygons I needed to straighten (you can see them highlighted) and chose "follow active quads".

However, the whole piece is adjusted to align with the main axes in the form of a true rectangle, which I did not intend (shape 2). The final result is also too long, comparing to the rest of the model I had unwrapped:

[image]

[image]

I am curious if this is the correct way for the "follow active quad" to respond, and if it is, How am I supposed to get the orange shape?
Thank you.

Comment: Hi :). In my wxperience 'follow active quads' gives you a (distorted) rectangle grid. You'll have to manually scale it to correct proportions ;)

Answer (score 1):

Follow Active Quads is used to get a grid of 4-sided faces that are following the active quad. So let say your active quad is distorted initially:

[image]

After Follow Active Quads you will get a picture like this:

[image]

As you see, Follow Active Quads gets initial quad and adds all faces around based on shape of active one, no matter what real size and shape it has.

So to get the form that you have, just unwrap the model using angle based method. It is the best way to do this, if you've set correct seams.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Actually, I had already used Angle Based in the previous screenshots, and this time I decided to give Conformal a try:    https://www.mediafire.com/file/99q8hvfovkoxh0w/angle+based-+conformal.JPG/file                                                                 As you can see, the result is much more like what I had intended, is this what you meant? @Crantisz